# df.style.highlight_max not supportive in Streamlit

Tags: pandas, highlight, streamlit

I am trying to build an interactive dashboard in `streamlit` and I am almost through with it barring this one problem of highlighting particular values in a similar set of columns. Because I am using a dynamic dashboard it takes values from the user and updates accordingly, where 12 common months are chosen and further mathematical columns are calculated, for eg: 202305 will have 202305_CAUTION as a new column.

This particular column has only 1 and 0 as values thus highlighting the max should work too, but it is not working, thus another block of code is written to define the colour structure as per the values

A snippet of my dataset

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7gXt.png)

I only want to highlight 0 and 1 in the columns that end with '_CAUTION' and here is what I have tried so far:

```
def color_survived(val):
        color = 'red' if val==1 else 'red' if val==1 else 'green'
        return f'background-color: {color}'

caution_ls=final_df2.filter(like='_CAUTION').columns.tolist()
st.dataframe(df.style.applymap(color_coding,subset=[caution_ls]))
```

I am getting this error

> Styler object has no attribute style

Is there anything wrong with what I am writing or is it simply an issue with streamlit not supporting Styler attributes?

Comment: `df.style` returns a `pd.Styler` object, not a dataframe. You'll need to do the highlighting with streamlit, not pandas style.

Comment: From what I gather from their website, they use df.style for highlighting only. Can you suggest a way around, I seem to be at my wits end with this one.